# ODBC Oracle Error

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle10g, odbc

I have a .net App I have been asked to modify, it uses .net framework 2.0

I have setup an ODBC DSN with the connection details for our Oracle DB on my local machine, Tested the connection and it works fine.

Now I ran my application, it went with no problem and finished, I had checked our error log and found a couple of errors unrelated to this issue but this error did not show up.

So I ran the app again with break points in order to get to these errors.  This time it crashed with the below error

> ERROR [IM004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle
>   on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed

Now what is getting me on this is that it just ran fine not even 10 minutes ago and I only added a break point.

I have found a few answers and gave them all a shot.

1. I set the Read/Execute on the oracle driver folder off than on to reset the permissions and it made no difference
2. I checked the "Path" Environment Variable and it is fine
3. Using the ODBC Administrator I tested the connection without error.
4. Verified the connection string pointing to the DSN is still correct 5. List item
5. Verified my App is setup to run 32 bit as the Driver is 32 bit.

The only thing I have not done is to save, shut restart computer and try again.. Which I will do right after this post, if it works I will post that.

Anyway if anyone has any idea what could cause this behaviour I would be very thankful to you.

Computer is Win7, .net FrameWork is 2.0 , it's VB.net, Oracle Driver is 10g (10.2)

Update:
okay I used the ODBC Administrator to remove the DSN and rebuild it.  I ran my app and it worked.

I came back later today after no changes and re-ran the application and got the error again.  tried to rebuild the DSN and it didn't help, I tried to restart and it didn't help.

Below is the stack trace.

```
StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
```

Comment: are you properly disposing of your connections?

Comment: I checked that, I thought it might not be but it seems to be I can't find anything that is open that doesn't get closed.

Comment: Can you try creating a very simple program just with the bare-bones ODBC calls, and see if that works?  Also, Microsoft used to have an app called ODBCTest, that let you call all the API functions directly for low-level testing.  See if you can find it and try it.  Also, did you try turning on ODBC tracing from the ODBC admin panel and see what gets logged?

Comment: Any update on this? Just curious.

Comment: I had the same issue a year ago. 

I fixed it by replacing the connection with the Oracle connection string in web.cofing file in my MVC applications. , if you need help on how to configure reply me back.

Comment: I had this same problem and what fixed it for me was to fix a broken symoblic link for the 32 bit oracle drivers in c:\windows\syswow64 and add that symbolic link folder to the PATH.  A server reboot was required for it to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this on a remote desktop?  If so you may have to add "Create Global Objects" for Remote Desktop Users to the Local Policy.

If you're on a local desktop, check the version of the ODBC driver you are running.  If it's anything older than 11.2.x.x, you should probably install a newer ODBC driver from Oracle (don't use the Microsoft Oracle ODBC driver - it has problems).